# Anti Forgery cookie issue after signout from IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am developing a solution with IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core 2.0.5. After logging out using HttpContext.SignOutAsync, the user can go on the login form again and try to login. However, the error message I get after form post in the console is:

```
The antiforgery cookie token and request token do not match.
```

I tried all options I could find on the internet. My configuration is as follows:

- IdentityServer4 is using a signing certificate (self-signed)
- ASPNET is configured to use data protection from Azure Blob Storage
- Login is performed with HttpContext.SignInAsync
- Logout is performed with HttpContext.SignOutAsync

Sometimes after second or third time try to login, it verifies the antiforgery cookie successfully. I logout and go to login page, the issue pops up again.

I got desperate trying different things. Is there anything that I might be missing when configuring IdentityServer or MVC?

Comment: Perhaps the login page is cached? Do you have this problem also if you refresh with ctrl-F5?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg no, caching is not an issue. I tried refreshing the page, doesn't help. The client app generates a unique URL to the login page of the identity server (the return url parameter).

Comment: Perhaps you should add some code and logging. It may be that you missed something in your configuration in Startup, or it has something to do with routing. Can you show the View and the Login/Logout code from the Controller?